# Setting token retrieved from response in Postman

Tags: postman

In tests section, I try to set token as Postman variable. I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Here's my script in test tab:

```
var data = pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set(“token”, data.token);
```

and here's my response for login:

```
{
"id": 1,
"username": "admin",
"name": "John",
"token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImV4cCI6MTU2OTY3ODg4NSwiaWF0IjoxNTY5MDc0MDg1fQ.k6aMQYo9uzC9jEXFvP1EZEUNEG_7VgEKxKmNtrZ9rSYvViHCNGYMaEpYY7MH8rYgtIg1Lpi4bfZEd9q2iOEOSQ"
}
```

Content type of response is **application/json;charset=UTF-8**.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the difference between `"` and `“`

```
pm.environment.set(“token”, data.token);
```

should look like this

```
pm.environment.set("token", data.token);
```

[image]